# How to check security token privileges in C#

Tags: c#, windows, permissions

I have an application that I want to be able to change system time.
But I only want to do this if the user has the SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME privilege, if he does not, I don't want to pop a UAC elevation dialog, I'll just silently do nothing.

I was trying to figure out if the .net framework has an equivalent to CheckTokenCapability.

Would the only way to achieve this be to pinvoke the win32 methods?

Comment: What is your Token?

Comment: Win32 has a series of Security Token related methods in Securitybaseapi.h. They are used to read and manipulate what kind of access you have to several system resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found no native way to do this in the .net framework.
Ended up using https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=processprivileges which uses the underlying win32 infrastructure.